# BCS External Item picker

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, external-list

There are two external lists like 'Project' and 'Task'. Task referencing project by using field ProjectID. I've created external content types. For 'Project' content type I've marked field 'ProjectName' as Title. For 'Task' I've added an association. Than created lists with InfoPath forms.

Here is a prblem: When adding or editing a task there is an item picker for ProjectID field. And when user have selected an item the ProjectID is shown in the box. Not the project name. When I've marked 'ProjectName' as Title for 'Project' content type it puts project name in the box but shows an error:

> No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for
>   more options. You can also use Select button to choose External Data.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to define filter parameters on your read list operation for your ECT in sharepoint designer. For example, create a wildcard filter for text filtering, and set it to default. Then that filter with your selected field will be the default search parameter in your external item picker.

1. In SharePoint Designer, navigate to `External Content Types`.
2. Right click on your External Content Type and select `Edit External Content Type`.
3. On the ECT settings page double click the Read List Operation.
   [image]
4. Click next on the Read List Operation's dialog window.
5. Click `Add Filter Parameter`.
6. On the right, click `(Click to Add)`.
7. There are some straight forward options you can pick here. I normally select `Wild Card` filter type as that will produce the most matches preventing the user from having to type the full name.

[image]

Selecting `Use to create match in external item picker` will create suggestion as you see in the next image:

[image]

Finally save the changes to your external content type and export the model if you need to add it to version control or need a backup of the current stae.

Comment: Adding explicit steps just for clarity.